# Migrating ArcGIS 9.3 to 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We have an older running ArcGIS 9.3 asp.NET application. Now we have installed 10.1 and started migrating. We had used Map Web Controls for displaying map in asp.net.Because there are some libraries deprecated in 10.1, in 10.1 environment, we got so many compilation errors. We solved one-by-one by commenting those codes. We do following things

1. Removed all Map Web Controls/Toolbar Controls and other controls.
2. We made a dummy class as "Map" with same properties and method for simulating older code and removing compilation errors.
3. Removed "using ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.UI.WebControls" references.

My question is ,

1. How much effort will required for migration?
2. How can we compare with the older system, because 9.3 is no more available?
3. We have used so many "ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF"'s client side apis also. What are the equivalent of those functions in 10.1 javascript apis?
4. Is any good documentation available related to 9.3 to 10.1 migration.

Comment: Do you have at least 2 testing environments?

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS 10.1, you can still use Web ADF for legacy applications (this is available for download via Esri Customer Care Portal and called `ArcGIS Web ADF (Microsoft .NET Framework)`).

1) It is not an easy task to migrate a 9.3 Web ADF application to 10.1. It will require a lot of effort. You should in first place evaluate whether you really need to stay within the Web ADF context; is there any specific case where Web Mapping APIs cannot be used? If it is a heavy ArcObjects thing that is used behind the scenes, you'll be so much better with [SOE](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000004s5000000)s. Another thing is that 10.1 is the last release of Web ADF which implies you'll get to migrate (or rewrite from scratch) your application again in the future if you will want to take advantage of the new functionality of the newer versions. Read more [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/04/27/considerations-for-arcgis-server-developers-a-look-toward-10-1/).

2) ArcGIS 9.3 is still available for use, talk with your local Esri rep, they should be able to supply you with the 9.3 release DVD. You cannot download 9.3 from Esri Customer Care Portal, but this should not be a problem to get from Esri distributor.

3) The Web ADF JavaScript Library is different from the ArcGIS JavaScript application programming interfaces (APIs) that are designed for pure JavaScript applications. The Web ADF JavaScript Library is packaged with the Web ADF and is designed solely for use with Web ADF components and solutions. ArcGIS JavaScript APIs are not designed for use with the Web ADF. Go through the pain of rewriting things and stay away from ADF; if the functionality of the JS API is not sufficient, go for a SOE.

4) Here are some of the resources (you will need to work with limited information here, though but the sooner you will go over to 10.1+ code the better it will be for you in the long run).

[How to migrate ArcGIS 9.3.x and 10 Desktop and Engine stand-alone applications to ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000002ns000000) (some parts are relevant for web too)

[Migration to ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000002p0000000)
[Migrating to ArcGIS 10.1 for Server](http://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.courseDetail&CourseID=50127141_10.x) (training course)

[How to migrate the Web ADF to 10](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/serveradf_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0002000001rw000000)

[GIS.se questions on Web ADF](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-web-adf?sort=votes&pageSize=50)

Esri Forums - search in google for "site:forums.arcgis.com web adf 10.1"